# GNU parallel with two arguments

Tags: parallel-processing, csh, gnu-parallel

I have a C-shell script with a variable called `$hosts_string` of the form:

```
host1,host2,...,hostN
```

I also have a variable called `$chrs_string` of the form:

```
chr1,chr2,...,chrM
```

I also have a variable called `$inputFn` which specifies a text file that I need to process.

What I'd like to do is have each host run a command called `doStuff` on each member of `$chrs_string`, taking `$inputFn` as the input filename argument.

I tried the following:

```
parallel -S $hosts_string 'doStuff {1} {2} > {1}' ::: {$chrs_string} ::: {$inputFn}
```

If this works, this should create files `chr1` through `chrM` as output from the command `doStuff`, but I get nothing. Parallel completes without issuing an error, but there is no output.

The command itself works fine if I don't use `parallel`, so it's not the command, but how I am specifying arguments to `parallel`.

To confirm this, I tried the following:

```
parallel -S $hosts_string 'echo {1} {2} > {1}' ::: {$chrs_string} ::: {$inputFn}
```

If *this* were to work, and `$inputFn` is (for example) `/foo/bar`, then I would get (for example) a file called `chr1`, containing the string:

```
chr1 /foo/bar
```

How do I adjust my `parallel` command so that it loops over each combination of `$chrs_string` and `$inputFn` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You just forgot ::: is not the same as ::::

```
parallel -S $hosts_string 'echo {1} {2} > {1}' ::: {$chrs_string} :::: {$inputFn}
```

If you just want the filename in the echo you simply do:

```
parallel -S $hosts_string echo '{1}' {$inputFn} '> {1}' ::: {$chrs_string}
```

Comment: This does not work. Simply trying `'echo {1} {2}'` shows the text content of `$inputFn`, not the pathname to that file. This is not correct behavior.

Comment: Then it is unclear to me what you want. I have edited my answer to give more ideas. If that does not answer your question, please post the output of 'parallel --version', the input and the expected output.